# Inline switch statement java?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Is there a way to implement an inline switch statement in java?

Right now, i'm using the following:

```java
    private static String BaseURL = (lifeCycle == LifeCycle.Production)
        ? prodUrl
        : ( (lifeCycle == LifeCycle.Development)
            ? devUrl
            : ( (lifeCycle == LifeCycle.LocalDevelopment)
                  ? localDevUrl
                  : null
            )
        );
```

I would much prefer it if I could do something like:

```java
    private static String BaseURL = switch (lifeCycle) {
        case Production: return prodUrl;
        case Development: return devUrl;
        case LocalDevelopment: return localDevUrl;
    }
```

---

> I do know you could achieve this by moving the `BaseURL` variable into a function `GetBaseURL` where the switch occurs *(see below)*, however I'm more so just curious if this feature even exists in Java.

```java
static String GetBaseURL() {
    switch(lifeCycle) {
        case Production: return prodUrl;
        case Development: return devUrl;
        case LocalDevelopment: return localDevUrl;
    }

    return null;
}
```

---

I'm transitioning from Swift, and in Swift I know you could do this:

```swift
private static var BaseURL:String {
    switch (API.LifeCycle) {
        case .Production:
            return prodUrl
        case .Development:
            return devUrl
        case .LocalDevelopment:
            return localDevUrl
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a `switch` statement? It would be much cleaner with a `Map`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming `LifeCycle` is an `enum`, then you're in luck, as [*switch expressions*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/325) were introduced as a preview feature in JDK 12. By using them, your code would look like the following:

```
LifeCycle lifeCycle = ...;

String baseURL = switch (lifeCycle) {
    case Production -> prodUrl;
    case Development -> devUrl;
    case LocalDevelopment -> localDevUrl;
};
```

If the `LifeCycle` enum contains more than those three values, then you'll need to add a `default` case; otherwise, it will be a compile-time error.